# Dictionary.app doesn't work in Google Chrome

Tags: macos, google-chrome, dictionary

From some point of time Dictionary stopped working in Chrome. When I tap with three fingers on a word, it shows the following window:

[image]

In all other applications Dictionary works well.

Chrome 41.0.2268.0 canary (64-bit) (Also tried 39.0.2171.95 (64-bit))

OS X Yosemite 10.10.2 (14C81f)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After yet another Chrome update it started working again.